# Set input invalid when typeahead-editable is false

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using typeahead's UI Bootstrap component and I want to force the selection to validate my form.

Is it possible to configure it to set the input invalid when `typeahead-editable` is set to false and the user enters a "bad" value or I should write a directive for this (but how)?

Comment: This bug has been fixed as of 2016, lol... see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NtGXL7uPLYKCHESnZyxs?p=preview

Answer (score 19):

The `typeahead` directive from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ has already support for limiting inputs to matches (in other words, people can bind to model only values available as matches in the typeahead popup). You can do this by simply setting `typeahead-editable='false'` attribute.

Please note that setting this attribute to `false` will *not* prevent people from typing-in invalid values. It will just make sure that a corresponding input is marked as invalid and a provided value is not bound to the model.

Comment: I know that editable set to false allow the user to enter any value. It just not set the model. What I found strange is that the input field is not "invalid" when the user enter a not selectable value. : [Example ](http://plnkr.co/edit/KbLOIRKHK5PdEIPvBCFV?p=preview). Or I don't understand something...

Comment: @JulienMeyer I see - you would like also set validity flag accordingly, right? This sounds reasonable, feel free to open issue for this in https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues?state=open

Comment: Yes. I will create an issue. Thank you

Comment: I see that there is an issue created for this. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2308 I however do not see a fix... I suspect this is a $scoping issue. The model.$valid is set to false but I don't think it is in the same scope as the form when the user types...

Answer (score -1):

Answer on the behalf of OP:

```
var formValidatorsModule = angular.module('app.validator.formValidator', []);

formValidatorsModule.directive('typeaheadForceSelection', function() {
    return {
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                if (viewValue == undefined) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('typeaheadForceSelection', false);
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('typeaheadForceSelection', true);
                }
                return viewValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
```