# multiple select dropdown with custom input for put our values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need a multiple select drop down with custom input field. I want to choose multiple options, if my option doesn't in the list, input field able to add my text.

I have seen some plugins like "chosen". But all they have filtering/autocomplete input box only.

I would appreciate if Any help, any plugin suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this link help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/bDvkQ/

```
<div id="testView">
<input id="testItems" data-role="multiselectbox" data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="Id" data-bind="source: testItemSource, value: testItems" />
```

Comment: the code in the link is not working, all I see is an empty input

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me. Just enable `"tags: true"`. For multiple select add `multiple="multiple"`.

For Example:

```
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
 tags: true
});
```

Reference: https://select2.org/tagging

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this by setting `typeahead-editable` to true in the directive? By setting it to true, it allows non-matched items to be bound to the directive's `ng-model`. I would just comment (not enough rep) but also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128793/set-input-invalid-when-typeahead-editable-is-false)